Etherscan API Key Issue with Foundry: Getting "Missing/Invalid API Key" Error
I'm having trouble using Foundry to download a contract's source code from Etherscan. Despite having a valid API key, Foundry returns a "Missing/Invalid API Key" error.

This is confusing because I've verified that the API key works fine with other tools.
Here's the command I'm using:
forge clone 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2 WETH9
And here’s a snippet from my foundry.toml file:
[etherscan]
  mainnet = { key = "my_actual_api_key_here" }

I've tried regenerating the API key, rechecking the setup, and even different configurations, but nothing seems to work. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
I expected Foundry to successfully fetch the contract's source code from Etherscan using the provided API key. I've double-checked the key in other applications, where it works perfectly. My expectation was that Foundry would perform the same without errors, but instead, it continually fails with the aforementioned error.
For additional context, I started my project by cloning the foundry-template repository using:

git clone https://github.com/PaulRBerg/foundry-template

I followed the steps outlined in the official Foundry documentation, specifically from this guide to clone a verified contract. Despite this, I'm still encountering the "Missing/Invalid API Key" error.

Etherscan is a service provided by a proprietary company. It would be better if you contact their support directly to resolve issues with them, as it is unfair to outsource the customer support of a commercial product to a community forum.

Thanks for the heads-up. I'm trying to figure out whether the issue is with Foundry or the Etherscan API. If it's the latter, I’ll definitely contact their support. Appreciate your understanding.

I'm trying to understand how Foundry uses the Etherscan API for forge clone, as it involves retrieving contract metadata via IPFS. This doesn’t seem solely like a commercial service issue but rather a technical integration question. Any insights would be appreciated.
